# How to dump a byte range from a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, dump, dd

How can I simulate

```
 dd if=LARGE_FILE skip=OFFSET count=LENGTH bs=1 of=OUTPUT_FILE
```

when LARGE_FILE lives in HDFS.

Comment: `hadoop fs -cat` will send a byte stream... Not clear why you need `dd`, or why you're using it to write to a file instead of using `-get`

Comment: I have external knowledge of a small segment in a large file stored in HDFS that contains the data I need. I would like to retrieve only that small segment of data from the large file (seems like a reasonable request to a file system). I could get the whole file back, or cat until the segment I want, but both those solution while yielding the right result are extremely inefficient for what I need.

Comment: My goal is not to write the small segment I retrieve from the large file back into HDFS, it is simply to process that segment's data. Maybe the analogy of=OUTPUT_FILE I chose was not the best one. I could have omitted that which would have meant stream to my next process:

dd if=HDFS_LARGE_FILE skip=OFFSET count=LENGTH bs=1 | process_small_segment

Comment: *seems like a reasonable request to a file system* .. HDFS is an abstraction , not an actual POSIX compilant filesystem. You need to collect the blocks of `LARGE_FILE`, merge them together, then you would be able to seek to the byte offset you wanted. At that point, you've already gathered all the block locations, so cat-ing or getting the file is essentially a similar operation

Comment: if a block in HDFS is a contiguous segment of the original file I can't understand why a request to retrieve a few blocks can't be cheaper than retrieving the content of all blocks. I agree we need to be aware of all block locations, but once we get that info (which should be tiny in comparison to the actual blocks), we could target only the small number of blocks intersecting the small segment requested.

Comment: This is assuming a file is splittable, and that you can know which file offsets a block contains